# How to Configure a Web Audio PannerNode to be Larger than One Point (volumetric)?

Tags: javascript, web, audio, web-audio-api

How do I configure a [PannerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode) to be volumetric?

There are many examples when this would be useful. Here they are from most simple to most complex. *note* I am using the X and Z values when referring to the user's position:

1. I want the sound of a road along the entire road. The road is a polygon:
   [[1,1], [1,100], [5,100], [5,1]]

Here is what should happen when the user is at different points along the road. You can test what actually happens with this [interactive example](https://codepen.io/frastlin/pen/zYNwaGJ):

```
1.1. The user is walking along side the road at [8,5], and they're facing with their left ear to the road (0,0,-1). They go to [8, 10], [8,15], [8,50] and the whole time, they are hearing the road at the same volume. Currently, the sound gets farther away behind as the user moves.
```

1.2. When the user is coming back down the y plane, they are facing the road, but they are at [3, 115]. Since they are facing the road with orientation (0,0,1), it should sound as if it is in front of the user. Currently, the sound is very far away and ahead.

1.3. When the user is at [3, 50], the sound should play equally in both ears.

1.4. If the user is facing (1,0,-1) and is at [8, 5], the sound should come from the forward right to the back left.

2. I have an object (a building with a pub in it) that is a right triangle shape, with a bounding box that is 10 by 10. I want to play the sound of the pub as the building. The building has the coordinates: [[1,10], [10,10], [10,1]].

2.1. When the user walks along the right side of the building [15,3], [15,6], and [15, 9], and the user is facing up the y plane, then the sound should remain constant in the left ear.

2.2. When the user is at [3,3] facing up the y plane, then the sound should be both to the right of the user, and in front of the user.

2.3. When the user is at [9, 9], the sound will play equally loudly in both ears.

I have been looking at the cone attributes (PannerNode.coneInnerAngle, PannerNode.coneOuterAngle, and PannerNode.coneOuterGain), but they look like they only deal with the 1 point size of the sound object and change what direction the sound is facing (like in the [Boombox example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Web_audio_spatialization_basics)).

I'm probably misunderstanding how the attributes work, but it doesn't seem as if the Web Audio API allows for multiple sized sound objects.

I have thought of two possible solutions, but both are ugly:

1. Calculate the nearest point to the listener, and change the object's position to be that nearest point every time the listener moves. When the listener is inside the object, the sound is positioned at the same location as the user.
   There are two major problems with this approach:
   1.1. It is extremely slow updating the nearest point of multiple complex objects.
   1.2. This approach does not handle sounds coming from multiple sides of the user, like example 2.2.
2. I can fill the object with PannerNodes, so for this one building, there would be 50 PannerNodes, and for the road, there would be 500 PannerNodes. This seems like an insane approach. How many PannerNodes can the browser handle at once? Also, if the user only moves half a point, then the sound may be grainy, as they're between two nodes.

Please let me know what I can do to make sounds larger than one point.

Thank you,

Comment: Could you try to clarify a bit your logic? Maybe with a simple graphic representing the situations. From here I'd say the easiest would be to have different PannerNodes and to switch which one is the active one based on your own logic, but I'm not sure to understand that logic to begin with...

Comment: I tried making it more clear on what I'm trying to do. I have a pub, and I want the sound of a pub to represent the building. The building is larger than 1 point though, so if I placed the panner node in the center of the pub building, it would sound far away if the listener was at the corner of the building. I want the entire building to be the panner node.

Comment: I think @Kaiido has the right idea. Have 2 PannerNodes, one from the centre of the building, the second an omnidirectional node in the same spot. As you approach the building fade from the building node to the omnidirectional node. You can play with the [roll off](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode/rolloffFactor) to reduce the effect of moving around the space.

Comment: Another example is I would like the sound of cars along a road that is over 100 squares long and 5 squares wide. The center is somewhere around 50 squares up from the bottom, but if the listener approaches from the short end, then they won't hear the road sound, since the node is in the center of the road, 50 squares away. But the road should be the same volume at the short end as it is when approaching the center.

Comment: Another idea is some kind of spatial audio as shown in Omnitone (https://googlechrome.github.io/omnitone/#gallery).  But the examples there have the listener stationary.  Not sure if that can be extended so that the listener is also moving through the space.  Creating the audio is fairly complicated, and perhaps better suited to real spaces.

Comment: Omnitone is very cool, but has no size operator in its API, and most of the sound sources sounded pretty much the same size as they moved around during the examples. It's also extremely difficult to judge size of a sound source without moving. I'm not sure I'm communicating what I'm looking for. If the road is a line: [[1,1],[1,100]] and the listener is at: [5, 10] facing so the left ear is facing the road, as long as the user is moving along the road [5,15], [5, 30], the sound of the road should remain constant in the left ear.

Comment: I added coordinates and rotation information to the question, so I hope that makes it more clear